# Laravel : Is it possible to use the Spread operator in a component constructor?

Tags: laravel, components, parameter-passing

I'm using the blade component system with Laravel 8.

I'm currently getting a lot of parameters to pass to a component. So I'm searching a way to pass parameters (or attributes) from the blade template into the component class constructor with the spread operator.

So :

```
<x-mycmp regularA="something" regularB="somethingelse" custom="test" />
```

To be understood by :

```
public function __construct ($regularA, $regularB, ...$addidionnalVars)
{
    // ...
}
```

Where the "custom" attribute will be in the $addidionnalVars array.

For now, I got a "laravel Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #2 [  ...$addidionnalVars]] in class" error.

Is there a way to make this works ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Solution below only seems to work for [Blade X](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-blade-x/v2/basic-usage/using-variables#spread-operator-for-attributes)**

This used to work for BladeX, maybe it works for you too?

```
<x-mycmp regularA="something" regularB="somethingelse" ...$spreadVariables/>
```

Comment: I saw this, but my goal is to keep the blade tag simple and recover all attributes without specifying all of them in the constructor. Because, I got componet with 15+ parameters to pass and lot of them is optionnal. And these vars can grow in number in time, and I do want to rewrite the constructor each time.

Comment: You could pass them as an array or a `Data Transfer Object`?

Comment: Yes, my first clue was to make a special attribute, :options="[...]", but my lead dev don't like to write this.

Comment: But maybe, this is just not possible with blade

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think it is possible indeed. I personally think `Data Transfer Objects` are the way to go to pass your data. Keeps your component constructor and view clean.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this way